# Visual Studio 2008 - Getting Data from Column of DataGridView in Selected Row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Code that I have so far is below. I want to get the data from the first column of whatever row is selected at the time.

```
private void btnGetCustomerID_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    String customerID;

    int rowInd = 0;

    rowInd = dgCustomers.CurrentCell.RowIndex;

    customerID = //NOT SURE WHAT TO PUT HERE

    txtCustomerID.Text = customerID;

}
```

Comment: BTW, this is the second question of yours which had "Visual Studio" in the subject, even though the question has nothing to do with Visual Studio. The same exact problem would have happened even if the code was developed using Notepad.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Wow you ARE a picky so and so aren't you. I simply put it because that's what i'm working in. Just thought that it might be useful to give a little background information. My apologies if you had that much of a problem with it!

Comment: @Kimmy: add all the _useful_ information you like. The fact that you were using Visual Studio 2008 was totally irrelevant to your question. It didn't even matter what version of .NET you were using (though you didn't tell us which version). There are tens of thousands of questions here a week - we don't need extra noise that doesn't help anyone to answer your question.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I don't see what your problem is really, i'm pretty sure I didn't hurt you by using those extra few words, but hey, if it pleases you to put people down by being so picky and making out that you're superior to them then go ahead. Looks like all you do is Edit peoples posts , boring day?

Comment: @Kimmy: you're new here and don't understand the site yet. Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and give yourself time to learn how this site works. It's not a discussion forum, so many things are different.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I used to be on here alot actually but I deleted my old email account and so on. I just think that most people come here for help instead of to be moaned at for putting in a 3 or 4 extra words that someone felt was irrelevant. Maybe you could concentrate on helping more :)

Comment: @Kimmy: it's not just about you. It's about everyone else who uses the site to get the same question answered. Noise and misdirection doesn't help with that. It's also about making questions  more attractive to potential answerers. Again, noise doesn't help that. If you _still_ don't get it after reading the FAQ, then spend some time on http://meta.stackoverflow.com to learn what's going on.

Comment: @JohnSaunders - Obviously you're only content being picky so i'll leave you to it. I'm pretty sure that I would prefer to answer a question that had 'Visual Basic 2008' rather than one that didn't because it would draw my attention to it. Have a productive day.

Comment: @Kimmy: not worth discussion - you didn't like the edit, so you reverted it. That's how it's meant to work. But, BTW, my attention was immediately drawn to your question - because it was obvious from the title that it had nothing to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I was working in Visual Studio - so obviously it did have something to do with Visual Studio.

Comment: @Kimmy: my simple rules: if the same problem would happen with Notepad, then the question wasn't about Visual Studio. If the same problem would happen with VB.NET, then it's obviously not a C# problem. If the same problem would happen with C# 1.0, then it's not a C# 4.0 question. Same with .NET 1.0, then not a .NET 4.0 question.

Comment: This works much better if you provide as close as practical to just the information necessary to reproduce and fix the problem, and not a lot of extraneous information. Examples of more extraneous information: it doesn't matter whether you are using the Professional or the Express version of Visual Studio. It doesn't matter which service packs you have installed. It doesn't matter which OS or OS version you're running, nor whether you're using the Home or the Enterprise editions. It doesn't matter what music you're playing, or what you had for lunch, either.

Comment: I wanted to know how to do it in Visual Studio though. I have never used a DataGridView in Notepad, neither did I know it was a possibility, but I will certainly experiment with that.

Comment: But Kimmy, notice that the answer had nothing to do with the IDE. If the answer had involved doing something with the property grid or in the designer, then I would have left "Visual Studio" alone in the title. Instead, the answer was a simple change to a line of text, a change which had nothing at all to do with which IDE you were using.

Comment: I wanted to know how to get the data from a cell, which indeed seems like it had something to do with the grid.

Comment: Kimmy: this may be what you don't understand. Visual Studio is just the Integrated Development Environment - the editor, the designers, the solution explorer,  menus, etc. The grid is not part of Visual Studio. It's part of .NET. C# is also not part of Visual Studio - it's part of .NET. Your question was about C# and the grid, and that's what the answer was about. It had nothing at all to do with Visual Studio (devenv.exe).

Comment: Yes, I know. However, i'm still pretty sure that saying that I was working in Visual Studio 2008 wasn't against the rules, nor a nuisance for anyone accept yourself. I would love to sit around and chat about this all day but I have things to do. So do enjoy your time on here.

Comment: @Kimmy: to [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) with you. Ask a question about this, and refer to this one. That way, it's not just my opinion and yours, you'll hear opinions both pro and con. You'll also be reminded that I said nothing about rules or nuisance. I said it wasn't relevant and in fact was misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Cells collection,

```
object firstColumnValue=dgCustomers.CurrentCell.Cells[0].Value;
```